# Symfony 4 - Modify field "name" on a radio button generated by Form

Tags: php, forms, field

I'm working with Symfony 4 on a project which goal is to make a quizz. I create a FormType named "AnswerType" that will retrieve user's answers. Here is my Form :

```
$builder
->add( 'answer', EntityType::class, [ 'class' => Answer::class,
    'query_builder' => function ( EntityRepository $er ) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder( 'aw' )->orderBy( 'aw.question' );
    },
    'choice_label' => 'description',
    'expanded' => true,
    'attr' => [ 'class' => 'form-check-input', ]
] );
```

And here is my problem, I created a twig and wanted to change the "name" field of my radiobutton generated by my AnswerType to give it the id of the question value so the answers will be linked to their questions (sorry for this messy explaination).

I tried this way but it doesn't work :

```
{{ form_widget(form.answer, {'attr': {'full_name' : '{{ question.id}}'}}) }}
```

I also tried this way but I think I don't have the right term after "block" :

```
{% block choice_widget %}
    {% set type = type|default('text') %}
    <input type="{{ type }}" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} name="{{ question.id }}"/>
{% endblock choice_widget%}
```

I hope you can help me ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I Think you want to check out this

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-value

With this you can specify which value should be used.

Edit:

Check out this documentation part for editing the label

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answers :) I read these documents but didn't find the way to do want I want. I tried to follow the explainations for the name but it didn't work :(                                <input type="radio" id="answer_answer_2" name="answer[ answer ]" required="required" value="6">                        It's the name attribute here I want to change, not the label :)

Comment: You cloud do something like this: 'choice_name' => function (?MyOptionEntity $entity) {
    return $entity ? $entity->getId() : '';
},

Comment: I tried this :                     'choice_name'=> function (?Answer $answer)
                    {
                        return $answer ? $answer->getQuestion()->getId() : '';
                    },                                                                                                               But field "name" didn't change neither and it gives me only the last answer of each question...